# FindBugs: INT_VACUOUS_BIT_OPERATION

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, findbugs

In order to convert from int to IP String I am using approach in [Going from 127.0.0.1 to 2130706433, and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241229/going-from-127-0-0-1-to-2130706433-and-back-again)

```
private static final byte BYTE_MASK = (byte)0xff;

protected byte[] unpack(int bytes) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte)((bytes >>> 24) & BYTE_MASK),
        (byte)((bytes >>> 16) & BYTE_MASK),
        (byte)((bytes >>>  8) & BYTE_MASK),
        (byte)((bytes       ) & BYTE_MASK)
   };
}
```

But `FindBugs` in `Eclipse` generates bugs: `INT_VACUOUS_BIT_OPERATION`.

> INT_VACUOUS_BIT_OPERATION: bit operations that don't do any meaningful work.

**Why is that and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's because you don't need the `& BYTE_MASK` if you're *also* casting to `byte`. I'm assuming that `BYTE_MASK` is 0xff... in which case it's basically pointless. Just casting will have the same effect.

From [section 5.1.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.