# Which representation took more memory and which one is efficient

Tags: java

I have a question. I have to process IP addresses and port numbers. Each packet contains source and destination IP, source and destination port. Let say a packet is (1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8,22, 8080) So I can store them in two different data types.

```
 String packet ="1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8,22, 8080";
 short[] packet={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22, 8080}
```

Which one will take more memory and which one is more efficient for processing

Comment: Will you be creating millions of these?  If not, don't worry about memory.

Comment: Depends on what kind of processing you want. Absent that, I'd probably use a class which wraps two `java.net.InetAddress` instances and two `unsigned short`s, as it gives you best readability and versatility. Optimise if you find you need to optimise.

Comment: Yes I have to process millions of records therefore memory and efficiency both are primary concerns

Comment: I think the java.net.InetAddress will take more space than using either string or short

Comment: @Amadan Java doesn't have unsigned types, and a `short` will usually end up stored as 32 bits anyway.

Comment: This is the worst sort of premature optimization. *Use the proper class* and only go back if it turns out that there's an *actual* problem. "Millions" of records is nothing in the age of gigabytes of memory on cell phones.

Comment: @chrylis: Derp. :) But yeah, premature optimisation. I believe (not 100% sure) that `java.net.Inet4Address` only stores a 32-bit number. Overhead might get you over the `short[]` size, but `short[]` would be harder to process (again, depending what processing you're doing). And besides, for certain types of processing, you don't need to have everything in memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

The `short[]` is 10*2 bytes, plus object overhead.

The `String` requires a delimiter, so it is at least 9*2 + 1 chars (if every number is a single digit) plus object overhead, and in realistic cases will be always longer.

So the `short[]` is both less memory and (I strongly suspect) easier to process.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, each IP carries 32-bits of data (4 8-bit values) and each port carries 16-bits of data. So your total record can be compressed into a total of 32+32+16+16 = 96 bits, or 3 32-bit `int` primitives.

You can use the answer from this question: [Going from 127.0.0.1 to 2130706433, and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241229/going-from-127-0-0-1-to-2130706433-and-back-again) to pack each IP address into a single `int` value. A similar technique can pack the two port numbers into a single `int` as well (since port numbers are are really up to 16-bit values).

With this "optimization", you can store a single record into 3 int values (which you could wrap into a class and provide utility methods to get each piece of data).

Comment: Nice way to save a few bytes.  Note that Java pads most objects to a multiple of 8 bytes (details vary) so you'd need to work out the details to see if this really saves or not.